# How to use ImageView as RelativeLayout background?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I need to use an ImageView as a layout background, because the image will be defined dynamically in code, from url, but the ImageView doesn't fit all the layout.

I've tried to use height as fill_parent, match_parent, use scale_type="fitXY", but doesn't work.

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_barra_dados"
    android:background="@color/com_facebook_blue">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_bg_perfil"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

                 <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_img_perfil">


                        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_perfil"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/botaorosa"
                            android:layout_margin="20dp"
                            />

                </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_dados_perfil"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_img_perfil"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                     <RelativeLayout
                         android:id="@+id/layout_nome_perfil"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_weight="1"
                         android:orientation="horizontal" 
                         android:layout_margin="20dp">

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/txt_nome_perfil"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="Danoel" 
                             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                         <ImageView
                             android:id="@+id/img_local_perfil"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/txt_nome_perfil"
                             android:src="@drawable/icone_local_perfil" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/txt_local_perfil"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/txt_nome_perfil"
                             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_local_perfil"
                             android:text="Belo Horizonte" />
                     </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout 
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:id="@+id/layout_status"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">


                                            <ImageView
                                                android:id="@+id/img_icone_feito_perfil"
                                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:src="@drawable/icone_feito_perfil"/>

                                             <TextView
                                                 android:id="@+id/txt_feito_perfil"
                                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                 android:text="10"
                                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_icone_feito_perfil"/>

                                                <ImageView
                                                android:id="@+id/img_icone_quero_perfil"
                                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                android:src="@drawable/icone_quero_perfil"
                                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_feito_perfil"
                                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

                                             <TextView
                                                 android:id="@+id/txt_quero_perfil"
                                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                 android:text="10"
                                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_icone_quero_perfil"/>


                            </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_barra_seguidores"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_barra_dados">

            <RelativeLayout 
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/layout_seguidores"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                         <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_header_seguidores"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/txt_header_seguidores"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/txt_seguir"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="10k"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/txt_header_seguidores"
                             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                             android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout 
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/layout_seguindo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                         <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_header_seguindo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/txt_header_seguindo"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/txt_seguindo"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="10k"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/txt_header_seguindo"
                             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                             android:textStyle="bold" 
                             />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout 
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/layout_pontuacao"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                         <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_header_pontuacao"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/txt_header_pontuacao"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/txt_pontuacao"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="10k"
                             android:layout_below="@+id/txt_header_pontuacao"
                             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                             android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_barra_lista"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_barra_seguidores"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn_seguir"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/botao"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:text="@string/btn_Seguir"
         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         android:textStyle="bold" />



         <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout_btns"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">



                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/btn_list"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_margin="20dp"
                     android:background="@drawable/icone_listagem01"/>

                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_grid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/icone_listagem02"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/img_barra_seta"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/barra_seta"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/layout_barra_lista"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDITED:**

Here's the code when load the image from URL

```
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getApplicationContext()));


            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

            ImageView imgPhotos = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo);

            imageLoader.displayImage(url, imgPhotos, options);
```

Comment: show the code you tried

Comment: can you post the code that you are using to set the image to the image view? Also, if you want the image to completely cover the "facebook blue" background you can set it as a background drawable on the RelativeLayout, rather than creating a separate imageview for it. Is there a specific reason you are using the ImageView?

Comment: I edited the question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android:layout_alignParentTop and android:layout_alignParentBottom, this way the image will be stretched.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:
Set the image as a background to the relative layout (`android:background="@drawable/WHATEVER"`)

OR

Move the ImageView to the BOTTOM of your code, instead or below

```
 <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/img_barra_seta"
```

Comment: I think, he has an ImageView and he wants to set it as a Drawable background from java. I also want to do the same. Can some provide any references??